# File Read and Write Operations query

Tags: android, file, file-io, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

```
package com.example.vibhor.myfile;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*final EditText ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final EditText ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);*/
        Button bn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button bn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        //final TextView tx1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

            bn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                EditText ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                EditText ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                String a=ed1.getText().toString();
                String b=ed2.getText().toString();


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("")||b.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Kindly fill the fields first",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    else {
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("mydata.txt", MODE_APPEND);
                            fos.write(a.getBytes());
                            //fos.write("/t".getBytes());
                            fos.write(b.getBytes());
                            //fos.write("/n".getBytes());
                            fos.close();
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), b, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data added in the file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


            bn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                TextView tx1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("mydata.txt");
                        byte[] reader=new byte[fis.available()];
                        while(fis.read(reader)!=-1)
                        {
                            String c=(new String(reader));
                            tx1.setText(c);
                            fis.close();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

I have inserted two EditText boxes in which i want the user to add some String which should be added to my file so created.

But the String which the user is typing in the EditText fields are coming blank in my File so created. So when I fetch the data it shows nothing as it does not have any fields in the EditText.

What can be done in this case?

Comment: `String a=ed1.getText().toString();
                String b=ed2.getText().toString();`. Move those lines to onClick(). You are too early now.

Comment: `fis.close();`. Take it out the while loop and put it below it.

Comment: `tx1.setText(c);`. If the while loop loops ten times only the last string will be in the textview. You overwrite former ones.

Comment: Thanks.. @greenapps